# Unknown Syntax Error on calling Pyrebase in Python

Tags: python, firebase, pyrebase

I don't know how to Summarize or Format the problem, I am providing the error

---

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "push.py", line 1, in 
>      from pyrebase import pyrebase
>    File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyrebase__init__.py", line 1, in 
>      from .pyrebase import initialize_app
>    File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 17, in 
>      from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
>    File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 25, in 
>      from oauth2client import client
>    File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 45, in 
>      from oauth2client import crypt
>    File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\crypt.py", line 55, in 
>      from oauth2client import _pycrypto_crypt
>    File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client_pycrypto_crypt.py", line 17, in 
>      from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
>    File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6.1-py3.7-win32.egg\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 75, in 
>      from Crypto.Util.number import getRandomRange, bytes_to_long, long_to_bytes
>    File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6.1-py3.7-win32.egg\Crypto\Util\number.py", line 139
>      value = 2L ** (N-1)                # Ensure high bit is set
>               ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> ---

I had errors installing Pyrebase so I am currently using Pyrebase4
I also tried installing PyCryptoDome and then installing Pyrebase manually after configuring to avoid versioning error
This is my code:

```
import pyrebase

config={keys and all go here}

firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db=firebase.database()

db.child("names").push({"name":"Abhinav"})
```

Expected to push data to Firebase

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error in a third-party library, it usually means you're using a different version of Python than the library is compatible with.

Comment: @Barmar I agree. I spent some time looking at the library's [github repo](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto), hoping to confirm that it wasn't compatible with Python 3 - but I couldn't see any sign of this, or see any syntax error near the highlighted line. However it became apparent that the library has not been maintained for 5 years, so it's probably not a good idea to be using it anyway.

Comment: In fact, it specifically says **PyCrypto is written and tested using Python version 2.1 through 3.3.**

Comment: Could you paste the traceback with proper formatting? There a `^` that points to where the invalid syntax is, but it's not helpful when you wrap all the lines.

Comment: missed that, thanks @Barmar. (I didn't realise changes of 3.x version could cause syntax errors though, just possibly different APIs in some modules.)

Comment: The problem is `2L`. That syntax isn't supported in Python 3.6. In Python 3, integers have unlimited precision, there's no distinction between `int` and `long`.

Comment: Maybe earlier 3.x versions supported it for backward compatibility, which is why it worked in their testing with 3.3.

Comment: It looks like they had a [thing](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/7acba5f3a6ff10f1424c309d0d34d2b713233019/setup.py#L70) that was supposed to run 2to3 on the code, but it doesn't seem to have triggered properly.

Answer (score 10):

if you have installed pyrebase (v3) and is not working just do

```
pip3 install pyrebase4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use Pyrebase4 instead of pyrebase 3

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
value = 2L ** (N-1)
```

to

```
value = 2 ** (N-1)
```

Python 3 doesn't have long integers, all integers are unlimited precision.

You may need to search the rest of the code for other long integers. You can use a regexp `\dL` to find them.

Comment: After sorting this out I am getting an import error for "No module named '_number_new'"

Comment: It's in the file `pycrypto/lib/Crypto/Util/_number_new.py`